# Returning data from getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a function that fetches data from The Guardian API but seem to be getting an error. The response returns this information:
[image]

And here is the code for the asynchronous function:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=xxxxxxxx&show-fields=thumbnail"
    );
    const { results } = await res.json();
    const newsList = results.map((news) => {
      return { ...news };
    });
    return {
      props: { newsList },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: @AidanHakimian "Error: Your `getStaticProps` function did not return an object. Did you forget to add a `return`?"

Comment: Your `map` statement doesn't make a lot of sense. Why aren't you just returning `results` from the function? All you're doing is creating a new array of the objects that are the objects in the `results` array.

Comment: @Andy I've done what you've suggested and returning the results back however I'm still getting the same issue. Could it be that results is inside of response? If that's the case, how would I map the results data?

Comment: @user14649590 you still haven't explained what the error is.

Comment: @Andy Your `getStaticProps` function did not return an object. Did you forget to add a `return`?

Comment: `getStaticProps` will always return a promise (because it's async), so how are you handling that when you call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. Only 1 thing you are missing is to return `props` even in the catch block

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=xxxxxxxx&show-fields=thumbnail"
    );
    const { results } = await res.json();
    const newsList = results.map((news) => {
      return { ...news };
    });
    return {
      props: { newsList },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return {
      notFound: true /// for rendering 404 page
    };
  }
}
```